# Using where clause with continuation in oData client using C#

Tags: c#, rest, odata

I'm using the Microsoft oData client to retrieve user information from a third-party API. I have the following code.

```
var query = Context.Users.Where(x => x.username.EndsWith("10"));
var result = query.ToList().Select(x => x.username);
```

However, this would only return 100 records. I can use the following code to retrieve all the records without the condition;

```
 DataServiceCollection<User> users = new DataServiceCollection<User>(
                    Context.Users
                );

 while (users.Continuation != null)
 {
     //use the token to query for more users
     //and load the results back into the collection
     users.Load(
         Context.Execute<User>(users.Continuation)
     );
     //print the current count of users retrieved
     Console.WriteLine(users.Count);
  }
```

How can I combine the two? i.e. to retrieve all the records with condition (x.username.EndsWith("10")).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it is a good practice to get only 100 rows at a time. But you can use the oDatas $top to get more than 100 rows. Microsoft oData client uses the the Take function for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/client/query-options

I should be able to combine the two simply by:

```
var result= Context.Users.Where(x => x.username.EndsWith("10")).Take(1000).Select(x => x.username);
```

Comment: No the records will not be retrieved at the same time in the second option. It will just make sure that all the records are fetched. The 'Take' will retrieve all the records at once.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using queries like this in oData Client version 7.6.2, but I think it will work in newer versions too.

```
var users = new List<User>();
DataServiceQueryContinuation<User> nextLink = null;
var query = Context.Users.Where(x => x.username.EndsWith("10")) as DataServiceQuery<User>;
var response = await query.ExecuteAsync() as QueryOperationResponse<User>;
do
{
    if (nextLink != null)
    {
        response = await Context.ExecuteAsync<User>(nextLink) as QueryOperationResponse<User>;
    }
    users.AddRange(response);
}
while ((nextLink = response.GetContinuation()) != null);
```

Comment: Hi Mikael i needed your example, but how about the second call with the next link how if you want to to have where clause there to? In the: `if (nextLink != null)
    {
        response = await Context.ExecuteAsync<User>(nextLink) as  QueryOperationResponse<User>;
    }`